# Replace an image in android/Java once a sound has stopped playing

Tags: java, android

I have an app which replaces an image and plays a sound on click of a button, What I am looking to do is revert back to the original image once the sound has stopped playing.

My button click listener:

```java
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Playing Theme";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            //this is the replaced image while the sound is playing
        imgSheep.setImageResource(R.drawable.replacedimage);

        Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
        playSound(R.drawable.sound);
    }
```

My Sound playing function:

```java
//plays a sound file
private void playSound(int sFile) {
    //set up MediaPlayer   
    final int medFile = sFile;

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            playSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), medFile);
            playSound.start();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

I know I can use a method like:

```java
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                performOnEnd();
            }

            });
```

So can I have it like this:

```java
    playSound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer playSound) {
                         imgSheep.setImageResource(R.drawable.originalimage);
                }
     });
```

Comment: It looks like you know generally how to do it.  So what problem are you having?

Comment: I added inside the onCreate instance and running the application gave me a FC error...

Comment: Post the stack trace from the log, and the code of your onCreate.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xbnm7Uwz pastebin link for my app

Comment: I would also like to display the PLAY button until the sound has stopped playing and re-enable it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your thread.  In playSound, you're starting a new thread which creates the media player and plays the sound.  However you're setting the onCompletionListener in onCreate.  There's a race condition there-  if the new thread isn't schedules and doesn't run and set the mediaPlayer variable before you hit that line, you'll crash with a NullPointerError.

I suggest just losing the thread.  MediaPlayer already will play in the background and not hang the UI thread.